# Searching a two dimensional array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, search

Total newbie here, having problems searching a 2 dimensional array.  I have a 3x3 char array that holds '1' thru '9' like a tic tac toe board.  For testing, I hard coded it to search for a '5', hoping it would return '1' for the row.  It returns '3' no matter what.  There are other posts similar, but they are all too advanced for what minuscule amount I know about c++.  Here is my array:

```
char board[3][3] =
{
    { '1', '2', '3', }, // row 0
    { '4', '5', '6', }, // row 1
    { '7', '8', '9' } // row 2
};
```

And here's my function:

```
int searchBoard()
{
    char board[3][3];
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            if (board[r][c] == '5')
            {
                return r;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Unless some code was left out, the second snippet is declaring a brand new 3x3 char array also named board, and never initializing it to anything.

Comment: BTW, you may return row *and* column (in a `std::pair` or a dedicated struct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your function `searchBoard` to

```
int searchBoard()
{
    char board[3][3] =
    {
        { '1', '2', '3', }, // row 0
        { '4', '5', '6', }, // row 1
        { '7', '8', '9' } // row 2
    };
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            if (board[r][c] == '5')
            {
                return r;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Quinn (and others), that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You should not declare a local, uninitialized `board` in `searchBoard()` which masked the global `board`.